# cross correlation function two intensity matrices 801x801

Tags: matlab, matrix, cross-correlation

I have two matrices

```
delta_Ire_plus = 801x801 double
delta_I_measured = 801 x 801 double
```

and I want to calculate cross correlation these matrices. I tried the following however it is not working

```
xcorr(delta_Ire_plus, delta_I_measured)
```

I also tried the following:

```
xcorr([delta_Ire_plus,delta_I_measured])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit

> Error using xcorr>parse_y (line 325)
>   B must be a vector (min(size(B))==1).

The input to `xcorr` *must* be a vector. Your data is a matrix which is causing the problem.

To compute the cross-correlation of two 2D matrices, you need to use [`xcorr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) instead

```
result = xcorr2(delta_lre_plus, delta_I_measured)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem with normxcorr2